How to loop through multiple tables to send to GCS?
I currently have a task where I need to move my external tables into GCS. For that, I'm using the MySQLToGCSOperator to move my external tables and schema to GCS; things like tables, columns, PKs, FKs. To do this process, I intend to use a dag to automate this process.
The issue I'm facing is the multiple databases, and associated tables within each database. For instance, I have a list of databases: my_sql_bds = ["appointments", "cards", "clinical-forms", "onboarding", "production", "systems-management"]
In each of those there are multiple tables.
The issue I'm trying to solve is getting the information_schema out for each table in each database.
Currently I first remove any of the files from the previous day:
def delete_temp_gcs_objects(gcs_hook, bucket_name, objects, delimiter):
    try:
        objects = gcs_hook.list(bucket_name, prefix=objects, delimiter=delimiter)
        for source_object in objects:
            gcs_hook.delete(bucket_name, source_object)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

From there I make setup my external mysql connection:
    def setup_connection(MYSQL_address: str) -> None:
        connection = Connection(
            conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
            host=ip_address,
            login=DB_USER_NAME,
            password=DB_USER_PASSWORD,
            port=DB_PORT,
        )
        """Make sure I kill connection after all jobs are done."""
        session = Session()
        log.info("Removing connection %s if it exists", CONNECTION_ID)
        query = session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == CONNECTION_ID)
        query.delete()

        session.add(connection)
        session.commit()
        log.info("Connection %s created", CONNECTION_ID)

    setup_connection_task = setup_connection(pull_mysql_address)

What I'm wanting to do is create a dictionary list for each database then make a mysql to gcs call to put the data gcs for each table's schema.

for db, table in my_sql_bds.items():
        MySQLToGCSOperator(
           task_id = "my_sql_to_gcs",
           mysql_conn_id = CONNECTION_ID,
           sql= SCHEMA_EXTRACTION
           bucket= DESTINATION_BUCKET,
           filename= f"/temp/mysql_transfer/{db}_information_schema.json"
           export_format="json"
  )

Then once I get the tables out, I want create a dictionary to list out the tables for each database(or folder) like so:
tables_dict = {
"appointments":[ "call_schedule", "call_config"],
"onboarding": ["address", "address_history"]
}

I'll then have to make another call using MySQLToGCSOperator to pull the columns:
for db, table in tables_dict.items():
    for i in table:
        MySQLToGCSOperator(
             task_id = "my_sql_to_gcs",
             mysql_conn_id = CONNECTION_ID,
             sql= COLUMN_EXTRACTION
             bucket= DESTINATION_BUCKET,
             filename= f"/temp/mysql_transfer/{db}/{i}/{db}_{i}_information_schema.json"
             export_format="json"

Could I get some help on the best way to handle this, please?
Originally it was just one table to GCS so this code was all I needed.
ops_mysql_to_gcs = MySQLToGCSOperator(
        task_id="ops_mysql_to_gcs",
        mysql_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        sql=OPERATIONAL_STAGING_EXTRACTION,
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        filename=STAGING_FILENAME,
        export_format="json",
    )

Now we are having more people wanting to test more datasets out that don't have access to out external tables.
